# HTML/CSS/Javascript Function Creation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a site that will convert your numbers. I have most of the code already, I'm just running into an error and can't figure it out. When I run it, there is code on the page and when I click the button, it won't run.

```
<div id = "conversion">
function feet() {
  var userinches = document.getElementById('userinches').value;
  doOuput('The answer is', userinches / 0.0833, ' ft');
}

function doOuput(val, unit) {
  //console.log('Convert To ' + unit);
  document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = val + unit;
}
</div><!-- End of conversion div section -->
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put javascript inside `script` tag.Better completely separate them from html file and write it in a separate js file. Include that js file in html

```html
<div id="question">
  <h2>Unit Convertor</h2>
  <img src="" alt="Picture of basketball">
  <p>Enter a Quanity of Inches: <input id="userinches" type="number" /> </p>
</div>

<div id="conversion">
  <script>
    function feet() {
      var userinches = document.getElementById('userinches').value;
      doOuput('The answer is', userinches / 0.0833, ' ft');
    }

    function cm() {
      var userinches = document.getElementById('userinches').value;
      doOuput('The answer is', userinches * 2.54, ' cm');
    }

    function yards() {
      var userinches = document.getElementById('userinches').value;
      doOuput('The answer is', userinches / 0.02778, ' yard');
    }

    function doOuput(val, unit) {
      //console.log('Convert To ' + unit);
      document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = val + unit;
    }
  </script>
</div>

<div="buttons">
  <button type="button" onclick="feet();">Feet</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="cm();">Centimeters</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="yards();">Yards</button>
  </div>
  <!-- End of buttons div section -->

  <div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use Javascript between `<script>` tag.
Please consider using an external file like in

```
<script src="myscripts.js"></script>
```